# How can I make user-entered messages with color codes specified with '&' display colored in-game?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am unsure on how to allow users of my plugin to enter color codes with `&` and have them display properly.  I know that I can use the constants in `ChatColor` to put various colors in messages sent by the plugin, but I don't know how to allow users to enter their own colored messages.

Here is my code:

```
package me.avy.simplemotd;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class motd extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + getConfig().getString("message"));
    }

    public void onEnable()
    {
      Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(" SimpleMotd enabled correctly!");
      saveDefaultConfig();
      Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    public void onDisable()
    {
      Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(" SimpleMotd disabled correctly!");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("motd")) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "MOTD: " + getConfig().getString("message"));
                    return true;
            }
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setmotd")) {
                    if (!sender.hasPermission("motd.set")) {
                            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are not permitted to do this!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a message!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                            str.append(args[i] + " ");
                    }
                    String motd = str.toString();
                    getConfig().set("message", motd);
                    saveConfig();
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "MOTD set to: " + motd);
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
    }
}
```

I want players to be able to use `/setmotd &cRed &aGreen &9Blue` and have the MOTD be displayed to them with the appropriate colors, using the [Minecraft color code format](http://wiki.vg/Chat#Old_system).  There are several other plugins that are capable of displaying messages set that way, so it must be possible.

How can I convert a message like `&cRed &aGreen &9Blue` into one that displays correctly in-game?

Comment: Please provide a correct format, so the precise part of code + precise question + precise problem encoured. Otherwise it's too dificult to every one to help you.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Zac, I just want to allow color code in the plugin. E.G. "&6"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html#translateAlternateColorCodes(char,%20java.lang.String)) to convert color codes using `&` to the format used by ChatColor.  (Internally, that's `§`).

`translateAlternateColorCodes` takes a replacement character and then the text to replace in.  For the replacement character, you would want to use `'&'` (note the single quotes and not the double quotes).  `translateAlternateColorCodes` has special logic to only replace valid codes, so `&eWelcome` becomes `§eWelcome` (which, in-game, is "Welcome" in yellow text), but `I like cats & dogs` does not get converted and displays in-game as `I like cats & dogs`.

You probably will want to do the replacement in all cases where the message is *displayed*, but not when it is set.  That way, if someone edits the config manually, `&` can also be used there.  As such, you'll want to edit your code to replace each of the following lines:

```java
p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + getConfig().getString("message"));
```

```java
sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "MOTD: " + getConfig().getString("message"));
```

```java
sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "MOTD set to: " + motd);
```

With these:

```java
p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', getConfig().getString("message")));
```

```java
sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "MOTD: " + ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', getConfig().getString("message")));
```

```java
sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "MOTD set to: " + ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', motd));
```

Better yet, you could write a `getMotd` method that retrieves the MOTD from the configuration with correct formatting, and use that instead:

```java
/**
 * Gets the MOTD from the configuration with formatting that can be used in chat.
 */
private String getMotd()
{
    String rawMessage = getConfig().getString("message");
    return ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', rawMessage);
}
```

You'd use `getMotd()` in all places you'd want to display your MOTD, rather than directly retrieving it from the configuration.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Now i understand it! Best answer i've seen all day jesus!

Comment: @avy Please mark this question as answered by clicking on the hook nearby this answer.